web3.js returns my id instead of result on Accountsubscribe so can't unsubscribe
Using the solana/web3.js sdk, when I use connection.onAccountChange which is basically the AccountSubscribe I get as result an id.
const subscriptionId = connection.onAccountChange(ata, (info, context) => {
 //some things here
});

This works great and I get all the data I am looking for but the subscriptionId that is returned is my own id and not the result id which is needed to unsubscribe. So when I use unsubscribe as follows:
await connection.removeAccountChangeListener(SubscriptionId);

I get an error message saying:

Ignored unsubscribe request because an active subscription with id 22 for 'account change' events could not be found.

So I am either using the SDK wrong or something else is off.
An other solution would be not using the sdk of course and use it directly as then I do get the full response back which includes that result id which is needed

It's hard to tell without more code, but the variable is called subscriptionId in the first snippet and SubscriptionId in the second -- is this just a typo?

it's 2 differents parts of the code.
// Subscribe to account changes
const id = connection.onAccountChange(, (accountInfo) => {
// Handle account change...
});
returns the wrong id, it retunrs the id you yourself set in the request. The sdk methode is a wrapper for https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/accountsubscribe which should return the result or the result and the id...but the result is the id we need to unsubscribe.
I have it working now without the sdk. Kind of confussing I guess as result is also an id...but hope you get it
